# Convert shapefile > 4 GB to ESRI Geodatabase

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, convert

I have 2 large shapefiles > 4 GB and 2 GB, is it possible using QGIS or ArcGIS to convert this to an ESRI Geodatabase so I can work with the data?

I have ArcGIS Advanced License 10.5.1 and QGIS 3.2.

I try adding them to ArcMap- right-click layer - Data - Export data, select file geodatabase as output but as far as I can see Arc doesn't support that file size for .shp files. So when I load them in, it doesn't load more than the 2 GB, which is also the only part that is converted to the Geodatabase. Hence I have a loss of data when converting that way.

Comment: `as far as I can see Arc doesn't support that file size for .shp files` , that's correct, the limit for any component file in a shapefile is 2 GB ~ https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/shapefiles/geoprocessing-considerations-for-shapefile-output.htm

Comment: If you have a file with a `.shp` suffix that exceeds 2Gb, it isn't a valid shapefile, and isn't likely to be successfully transferred to another geodata format (you'll need to go back to the source)

Answer (score 1):

The obvious suggestion is to split your shapefile with an external program.

- Check if you have a data interopability licence, which basically translates 'FME'. It has the functionality that you want (plus you can translate it directly)
- You can use OGR (bundled with a GDAL installation) to split your shapefiles. More info now you can do that, see how to [Split SHP file using ogr2ogr](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/176622/split-shp-file-using-ogr2ogr)